# How to implement dependency injection in an MSTest project using Startup.cs and Assembly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, mstest

In our application, I have used Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core 2. I have implemented dependency injection in a Web project `Startup.cs` class. I have to implement the same in a new test project. How can I inject dependencies of repositories in the test project?

Please see the below code snippet

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using NLog.Web;

namespace Kpmg.Kdat.Data.Services.Directory.Tests
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BuildWebHost(args).Run();
        }

        public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseNLog()
                .Build();
    }
}
```

The purpose of the above code is to inject dependencies. In `Startup.cs` I have configured all the dependencies.

While using the above code I am getting the below error:

> Error    CS0017    Program has more than one entry point defined. Compile with /main to specify the type that contains
>   the entry point.

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to include the above in your unit test project? Generally, you shouldn't have to.

If you want mock dependencies, in your unit test project you can do something like this.

```
public class TestServiceModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(ctx =>
        {
            // Return mock implementation of IMyService
        }).As<IMyService>()
        .SingleInstance();

        // Register your mock services like above
     }
 }
```

And use like,

```
[TestInitialize]
public void Initialize()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule<TestServiceModule>();
}
```

Now you can use IMyService.

Comment: To configure dependencies. In Startup.cs I have written all the dependencies.

Comment: I am sorry If I am being so dumb. What do you mean dependencies?

Comment: Written serviceCollection.AddTransient in Startup.cs

Comment: This shouldn't the question answer, since it does not answer the question.